# How to resave all my nodes

Tags: 8, views

In D7, it was easy with the VBO module..
But how to do it with D8? (Preferably using a view to select the nodes to resave)

In many places I saw that a small part of the VBO module is now included in the D8 core but I can't figure out how to use it (assuming a simple save should be feasible)

Comment: Can I know why you want to do this? Is just to know if I can use this solution in other moment.

Comment: This is because I have updated a node_presave function which is updating some other nodes depending on the value of the currently saved node.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you are asking for is included in core Views, unless I am mistaken.
In a new Content view you will be able to add a "Content: Node operations bulk form" field and that offers you an option for "Save content".

[image]

You could even use the default "Content" view...

[image]

that already offers that option out of the box:

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Latest update:

Drush core now also provide a re-save command! (since [v11.0.0-rc1](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/releases/tag/11.0.0-rc1))

```bash
# Re-save all article entities:
drush entity:save node --bundle=article

# Re-save all shortcut entities:
drush entity:save shortcut

# Re-save nodes 22 and 24:
drush entity:save node 22,24

# Re-save all nodes except node 9, 14 and 81:
drush entity:save node --exclude=9,14,81

# Re-save all users:
drush entity:save user

# Re-save all node entities in steps of 5, defaults to 50 if omitted:
drush entity:save node --chunks=5
```

---

Update:

Aaaand some folks also created an unattributed copy of Resave All Nodes and added some more options: [Save All Nodes](https://www.drupal.org/project/save_all_nodes).

---

Update:

I just created [Resave All Nodes](https://www.drupal.org/project/resave_all_nodes). For now it only contains a form and a Drush command to trigger a batch process to resave all nodes of selected node types.

[image: Drupal Resave All Nodes form screenshot]

---

For everybody coming here to find a code snippet (to be placed in `MYMODULE.install`):

```php
use \Drupal\node\Entity\Node;

/**
 * Resave all pages.
 */
function MYMODULE_update_8001(&$sandbox) {

  // Get an array of all 'page' node IDs.
  $nids = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
    ->condition('type', 'page')
    ->execute();

  // Load all the nodes.
  $nodes = Node::loadMultiple($nids);
  foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    $node->save();
  }
}
```

Problem with this, of course, is you can reach your memory limit pretty fast when re-saving many thousands of nodes that way. So you have to implement a batch process.

Thankfully [`hook_update_N(&$sandbox)`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Extension%21module.api.php/function/hook_update_N/8.4.x) already has this capability built-in. Follow the link for sample code.

> If running your update all at once could possibly cause PHP to time
> out, use the `$sandbox` parameter to indicate that the **Batch API** should
> be used for your update. In this case, your update function acts as an
> implementation of `callback_batch_operation()`, and `$sandbox` acts as the
> batch context parameter. In your function, read the state information
> from the previous run from `$sandbox` (or initialize), run a chunk of
> updates, save the state in `$sandbox`, and set `$sandbox['#finished']` to
> a value between `0` and `1` to indicate the percent completed, or `1` if it
> is finished (you need to do this explicitly in each pass).

Comment: Rather than messing with the sandbox, just iterate over the $nids and load the node inside the loop.

Comment: @Jonathan – Bad idea with 1.000.000 nodes.